# How to persist config/data for Jelastic Mosquitto

Tags: mosquitto, jelastic

I have created new Mosquitto node in Jelastic as described in [documentation](https://jelastic.com/blog/eclipse-mosquitto-mqtt-for-iot-networks-in-the-cloud/).

How can I make persistent data/config volumes for it in order not to loose data when e.g. upgrading docker image?

Answer (score 1):

There were two volumes already added before:
/mosquitto/data and /mosquitto/logs,
one more volume (/mosquitto/config) was added recently,
new updated package was already published to Marketplace.
Cheers!

Comment: thanks. maybe dummy question, but how can I "persist" volumes. I haven't notice such option during creation from marketplace.

Comment: It does already persist. Redeploy doesn't break the data on these paths. If you want to specify custom volumes paths, check the original JPS file:
https://github.com/jelastic-jps/mosquitto/blob/master/manifest.jps

Also, you can learn this and linked articles to make sure how it works:
https://docs.jelastic.com/local-filesystem-storage